# Are the computers in Severance real?

Tags: realism, props, severance

[image: a computer in Severance]

Is this computer, as in hardware, fictional? It has a very strange keyboard layout.

Everything with the computers is wrong, given the high-tech background of Lumon Industries.

Comment: "Wrong" is very subjective: can you expand on that?

Comment: @Joachim, resolution is very low, color is black / white, keyboard arrow keys are next to the mouse ball, display is CRT, display does not take up all the space (there is a addtional space to the right of display), there is a handle to the right of the monitor.

Comment: You could just swap the word 'wrong' for 'anachronistic'  or 'antiquated' & preserve the overall meaning of the question.

Comment: @Joachim You just know when something wrong. You see it, and you can feel that there's something not right about it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

They're props, but the design is based on a real terminal screen/keyboard from the 70's

The entire design premise of the show is based on an uncertainty of where we are in time.

> *"We wanted to confuse the viewer about whether this is a period piece, contemporary, or the future."*

> The "Lumon Industries" terminals are based on the [Data General Dasher
> D2](http://maas-interface-exhibition.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/object/dasher-d2-computer-terminal/index.html) or D3 terminals (circa 1977/1979), but, according to production
> designer Jeremy Hindle and set decorator Andrew Baseman, "any single
> brand of computer would be too identifiable for viewers".
>
> *“We brought in every imaginable desktop we could think of. [...] We
> made a computer that, if it ever came out in the real world and the
> engineers described what they were doing, no one would believe them.
> It’s a cathode-ray tube, but it’s a touchscreen. It has a trackball.
> We recognize some aspects of it, and some not at all.”
>
> The contradictory qualities are supposed to be baffling but also a bit amusing. “It doesn’t look like an adult high-tech computer,” Baseman added. “It looks like a toy.”*

Quote from [Keyboard Builders' Digest / Keyboard Spotting - Severance terminal](https://kbd.news/Severance-terminal-1353.html) itself quoted from [Vulture - The Stories Behind Severance’s Eerie Office Design](https://www.vulture.com/article/severance-office-design-explained.html)

I chose this particular one because underneath it has…

> u/gza-genius posted [some photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiWNN.jpg) with the title:
>
> *My buddy made the keyboards in Apple TV’s “Severence”*

[image]

[image]

…and as some else noted, "There's no Escape." Quite fitting.

Original Dasher D2, for comparison…

[image]  [image]

Comment: Not seen the show but love that the designers gave nods to so many of the computers and terminals of yesteryear but also infusing the modern era. Nice details. The kind of prop/concept that would be fun to work on.

Comment: Cathode-ray with a touchscreen and a trackball is fairly normal for some naval computers...

Comment: Are you talking about the aspect ratio of the overall enclosure? The aspect ratio of the screen itself is squatter than 4:3, not wider.

Comment: I've dropped the 4:3 paragraph because when you actually measure them, after a perspective crop, they're nearly the same - both very slightly wider than a 4:3 aspect. The cases makes them look more different than they really are.

Comment: @fectin - same for air force but they didn't come to mind when seeing these. Although I have a nostalgic fondness for orange graphics on black...

Comment: I love how the prop's screen isn't even clearly a CRT - the touch function probably uses a flat piece of glass in front, which hides the curve of the tube.  It could be visually confused with an LCD panel (which would also help with matching frame rates to avoid flicker)

Comment: @Criggie - I'd noticed the prop screen looks flat whereas the one from the show looks curved. Whether that's CGI or they added a curved glass front, we may never know.  It's not important whether the screen actually has any touch facility, or even that there's any 'computer' in there at all. Usually things like this are just playing video, so precise timing can be achieved, take after take if necessary.

Comment: I was pretty sure that computer graphics were almost always added in post-filming, due to problems with flicker.

Comment: @MooingDuck - LCD screens just don't have the issues CRTs had. The prop screens will be LCD, pretending to look like CRT. Simple test - point your phone camera at your computer screen… no flicker. Modern video cameras have an anti-flicker setting anyway, though that's usually only used near domestic lighting, which is horribly flickery.

Answer (score 17):

No. According to [this interview in the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/05/04/style/severance-props-catherine-miller.html), it was a custom designed prop. However, it was inspired by vintage and classic computer designs from the 80s and earlier. In particular, the [Data General Dasher](https://www.pdp-11.nl/dg/d200/dasher200.html):

[image: A Data General Dasher D200. A low and boxy screen with a curved shrouding cover sits behind a boxy keyboard]

The [museum which the product designer probably visited to get inspiration seems to have a slightly different Dasher](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/comments/ms0f6m/saw_a_dasher_d2_in_the_museum_today/) with a monitor that looks more like what they used in the show:

[image: A Dasher with a large rectangular monitor. The screen itself is square and offset to the left. It is mounted on a brack stand allowing the monitor to be angled up and down]

As for the odd keyboard design in the show, while the Dasher seen above has something more familiar to modern computer users, but it wouldn't be unusual for various computers throughout history to have certain customisations to fit specific requirements. It's really only since the late 80s and early 90s that computers and keyboards became highly standardised and generalised (though there are still custom layouts).

Comment: It was the Dasher D2, i.e your second image, which is not a prop, it's a real Dasher.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's possibly an original monitor - though there are subtle differences between the museum piece and the monitor in the show. The keyboard is custom, though.

Comment: Your picture is definitely a real Dasher. The screen is a different ratio to the one in the show too. The show's keyboard has no 10-key or command block, but an additional trackball.

Answer (score 4):

They're custom-designed by the prop department, but they're "real" in that they're fully functional computers that the actors  actually use on-set. [Per The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/23013413/severance-apple-tv-plus-production-design-computers):

> Hindle says that the computers are functional and that the actors are really messing with numbers on screen during the show. The machines also went through multiple revisions before production began to get the size just right (among other things), so that they were large enough to be a focal point but small enough to not obscure the actors or interfere with their eyelines.